# Copying an item from one list to another

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a to-do list that allows the user to add and delete tasks.  I'm trying to make it so the user can move one task from one list to another list.  This is the code that I currently have.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'm guessing the problem is somewhere in my JavaScript.

**HTML:**

```
<input type='checkbox' id="togglelist1" class='arrow'/>
  <label for="list1menu">
    <input type="text" name="newlist1" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New List" id="newlist1">
    <ul id="list1UL">
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="newlist1item" class="right-margin"><label>List1</label> <button type="button" class="deletelist"> </button> <button type="button" class="addtolist2"></button></li>
    </ul>
  </label>

<input type='checkbox' id="togglelist2" class='arrow'/>
<label for="list2 menu">
  <ul id="list2UL" class='list2UL'>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="newlist2item" class="right-margin"><label>List2</label> <button type="button" class="deletelist"></button></li>
  </ul>
</label>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(() => {
  $('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const newList1 = $(this).val();
      if (newList1) {
        var li = $("<li><input type="checkbox" id="newlist1item" class="right-margin"><label>List1</label> <button type="button" class="deletelist"> </button> <button type="button" class="addtolist2"></button></li>");
        $('#list1UL').append(li);
        $(this).val("");
        localStorage.setItem("list1UL", value);
      }
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".deletelist", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
  $(".addtolist2").on( "click", function() {
    $(".addtolist2").css("opacity", 1.5 - $(".addtolist2").css("opacity"));
    $(".addtolist2").toggleClass("list2UL");
    $('#list1UL input:checked').parent().clone().appendTo('#list2UL');
});
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#togglelist1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('list1.png') no-repeat;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#togglelist2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('addtolist2.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

*____List 1____*

```
label[for="list1menu"] {
  display: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 250px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 680px;
  height: 540px;
}

input[name="newlist1item"] {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 418px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  outline:0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#togglelist1:checked ~ label[for="list1menu"] {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: 55px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 860px;
}

label[for="list1menu"] h1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  left: 85px;
  top: 5px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

*____List 2____*

```
label[for="list2menu"] {
  display: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 250px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 680px;
  height: 540px;
}

ul[class='list2UL'] {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 142px;
  left: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 355px;
}

#togglelist2:checked ~ label[for="list2menu"] {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: 55px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 860px;
}

#togglelist2:checked ~ .list2UL {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  left: 85px;
  top: 5px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

label[for="list2menu"] h1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  left: 85px;
  top: 5px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#togglelist2:checked ~ ul[class='list2UL'] {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  left: 85px;
  top: 5px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is “the problem”? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Don’t guess. For example, you haven’t escaped the `"` in your string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. which will allow you to add - edit and delete task.

```js
//Document is the DOM can be accessed in the console with document.window.
// Tree is from the top, html, body, p etc.

//Problem: User interaction does not provide the correct results.
//Solution: Add interactivity so the user can manage daily tasks.
//Break things down into smaller steps and take each step at a time.


//Event handling, uder interaction is what starts the code execution.

var taskInput=document.getElementById("new-task");//Add a new task.
var addButton=document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];//first button
var incompleteTaskHolder=document.getElementById("incomplete-tasks");//ul of #incomplete-tasks
var completedTasksHolder=document.getElementById("completed-tasks");//completed-tasks


//New task list item
var createNewTaskElement=function(taskString){

 var listItem=document.createElement("li");

 //input (checkbox)
 var checkBox=document.createElement("input");//checkbx
 //label
 var label=document.createElement("label");//label
 //input (text)
 var editInput=document.createElement("input");//text
 //button.edit
 var editButton=document.createElement("button");//edit button

 //button.delete
 var deleteButton=document.createElement("button");//delete button

 label.innerText=taskString;

 //Each elements, needs appending
 checkBox.type="checkbox";
 editInput.type="text";

 editButton.innerText="Edit";//innerText encodes special characters, HTML does not.
 editButton.className="edit";
 deleteButton.innerText="Delete";
 deleteButton.className="delete";



 //and appending.
 listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
 listItem.appendChild(label);
 listItem.appendChild(editInput);
 listItem.appendChild(editButton);
 listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
 return listItem;
}



var addTask=function(){
 console.log("Add Task...");
 //Create a new list item with the text from the #new-task:
 var listItem=createNewTaskElement(taskInput.value);

 //Append listItem to incompleteTaskHolder
 incompleteTaskHolder.appendChild(listItem);
 bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);

 taskInput.value="";

}

//Edit an existing task.

var editTask=function(){
console.log("Edit Task...");
console.log("Change 'edit' to 'save'");


var listItem=this.parentNode;

var editInput=listItem.querySelector('input[type=text]');
var label=listItem.querySelector("label");
var containsClass=listItem.classList.contains("editMode");
  //If class of the parent is .editmode
  if(containsClass){

  //switch to .editmode
  //label becomes the inputs value.
   label.innerText=editInput.value;
  }else{
   editInput.value=label.innerText;
  }

  //toggle .editmode on the parent.
  listItem.classList.toggle("editMode");
}




//Delete task.
var deleteTask=function(){
  console.log("Delete Task...");

  var listItem=this.parentNode;
  var ul=listItem.parentNode;
  //Remove the parent list item from the ul.
  ul.removeChild(listItem);

}


//Mark task completed
var taskCompleted=function(){
  //console.log("Complete Task...");
 
 //Append the task list item to the #completed-tasks
 var listItem=this.parentNode;
 completedTasksHolder.appendChild(listItem);
    bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskIncomplete);

}


var taskIncomplete=function(){
  //console.log("Incomplete Task...");
//Mark task as incomplete.
 //When the checkbox is unchecked
  //Append the task list item to the #incomplete-tasks.
  var listItem=this.parentNode;
 incompleteTaskHolder.appendChild(listItem);
   bindTaskEvents(listItem,taskCompleted);
}



var ajaxRequest=function(){
 //console.log("AJAX Request");
}

//The glue to hold it all together.


//Set the click handler to the addTask function.
addButton.onclick=addTask;
addButton.addEventListener("click",addTask);
addButton.addEventListener("click",ajaxRequest);


var bindTaskEvents=function(taskListItem,checkBoxEventHandler){
 //console.log("bind list item events");
//select ListItems children
 var checkBox=taskListItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
 var editButton=taskListItem.querySelector("button.edit");
 var deleteButton=taskListItem.querySelector("button.delete");


   //Bind editTask to edit button.
   editButton.onclick=editTask;
   //Bind deleteTask to delete button.
   deleteButton.onclick=deleteTask;
   //Bind taskCompleted to checkBoxEventHandler.
   checkBox.onchange=checkBoxEventHandler;
}

//cycle over incompleteTaskHolder ul list items
 //for each list item
 for (var i=0; i<incompleteTaskHolder.children.length;i++){

  //bind events to list items chldren(tasksCompleted)
  bindTaskEvents(incompleteTaskHolder.children[i],taskCompleted);
 }




//cycle over completedTasksHolder ul list items
 for (var i=0; i<completedTasksHolder.children.length;i++){
 //bind events to list items chldren(tasksIncompleted)
  bindTaskEvents(completedTasksHolder.children[i],taskIncomplete);
 }




// Issues with usabiliy don't get seen until they are in front of a human tester.

//prevent creation of empty tasks.

//Shange edit to save when you are in edit mode.
```

```css
/* Basic Style */
body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
}
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li * {
  float: left;
}
li, h3 {
  clear:both;
  list-style:none;
}
input, button {
  outline: none;
}
button {
  background: none;
  border: 0px;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover {
  color: #333;
}
/* Heading */
h3,
label[for='new-task'] {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 30px 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  color: #888;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  color: #333;
}

/* New Task */
label[for='new-task'] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
input#new-task {
  float: left;
  width: 318px;
}
p > button:hover {
  color: #0FC57C;
}

/* Task list */
li {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
li > input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}
li > label {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 237px;
  padding: 0 0 0 11px;
}
li >  input[type="text"] {
  width: 226px;
}
li > .delete:hover {
  color: #CF2323;
}

/* Completed */
#completed-tasks label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #888;
}

/* Edit Task */
ul li input[type=text] {
  display:none;
}

ul li.editMode input[type=text] {
  display:block;
}

ul li.editMode label {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Todo App</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        <label for="new-task">Add Item</label><input id="new-task" type="text"><button>Add</button>
      </p>
      
      <h3>Todo</h3>
      <ul id="incomplete-tasks">
        <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Pay Bills</label><input type="text"><button class="edit">Edit</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
        <li class="editMode"><input type="checkbox"><label>Go Shopping</label><input type="text" value="Go Shopping"><button class="edit">Edit</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
        
      </ul>
      
      <h3>Completed</h3>
      <ul id="completed-tasks">
        <li><input type="checkbox" checked><label>See the Doctor</label><input type="text"><button class="edit">Edit</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have an issue with JS here

```
$(".addtolist2").on( "click", function() {
  $(".addtolist2").css("opacity", 1.5 - $(".addtolist2").css("opacity"));
  $(".addtolist2").toggleClass("list2UL");
 $('#list1UL input:checked').parent().clone().appendTo('#list2UL');
});
```

Here you are doing some kind of CSS change and class toggling when button is clicked in first two lines but in the 3rd line you are doing something weird. I am not sure why you need to do this but as per your HTML markup it looks like you want to copy the item to second list when somebody click the button next to the item in the first list.

Here is the correct implementation for the above case which will copy your item from first list to second list whenever you click the button corresponding to the item in the first list.

```
$("addtolist2").on("click", function(){
 $(this).parent().clone().appendTo("#list2UL");
});
```

Please note this code will not remove the current element from list1. If you want to do so, you can remove $(this).parent()

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried this in my code but it is not working.  I think it is because the list class itself is changing from "addtolist2" to "addtolist2 list2UL".